# Match multiple lines in a file using regular expression python

Tags: python, regex

I have some many files each file has a set of lines in a given pattern. I want to match those multiple lines at once and do some operations on them such as delete, move to another file etc.

the multiple lines in a file are as given below.

```
self.unsupported_cmds = [r'\s*clns\s+routing',

                         r'\s*bfd\s+graceful-restart',

                         r'\s*ip\s+default-network',

                         r'\s*ip\s+default-gateway',

                         r'\s*ip\s+subnet-zero',

                         r'\s*ip\s+cef\s*$' ]
```

The lines within square brackets may vary.

Help me how to do it.

Comment: Please add four leading spaces for all the code. Formatting is a bit complicated to understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As python `re` module [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.compile) says you may add the `MULTILINE` flag to `re.compile` method. This will let you match entire file at once.

```
import re

regex = re.match(r'''(
    ^\s*clns\s+routing$ |
    ^\s*bfd\s+graceful-restart$ |
    ^\s*ip\s+default-network$ |
    ^\s*ip\s+default-gateway$ |
    ^\s*ip\s+subnet-zero$ |
    ^\s*ip\s+cef\s*$
)+''', re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)
```

Notice that I've added `VERBOSE` flag to write regex with additional formatting to make regex look nicer. Also you should see that there are several `^` and `$` symbols. That is how multiline regex allows you to match over multiple lines in one file.

Additionally I must warn you that this regex will only help to match file just to be sure is entire file correctly formatted. If you want to parse data from this file you need to modify this regex a little to satisfy your needs.

Second code variant

```
import re

regex = re.match(r'''(^
    \s*
    (clns|bfd|ip)
    \s+
    (routing|graceful-restart|default-network|default-gateway|subnet-zero|cef)
$)+''', re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)
```

Comment: Could you please provide me the regular expression to match above set of lines?

Comment: This is cool, but  the lines with in the brackets many vary. Can you provide me a better solution?

Comment: @ameet what you mean under word "vary"? I've added `+` that was missed. Now this regex will match any file that consists of the lines you've provided in any order.

Comment: @ameet, you could use `'|'.join(list_of_regexps)` every time `list_of_regexps` changes.

Comment: @ameet I've added second regex variant to let you additional example for better understanding. The second variant let you match the strings that consist of the any combination of the positional words from your question.

Comment: @ameet I think no one could provide you any solutions here. We just answering your question. It is only you who knows the correct solution that will solve your task.

Comment: This is very useful, Thanks Lig and Kirill.